# Property 'config' does not exist on type 'BrowserObject' in Webdriver.io

Tags: testing, webdriver-io

I'm using webdirevio to make some tests, and I'd like to access the configs from the tests as described here:

https://webdriver.io/docs/browserobject.html

But when I write `browser.config` in my tests I get the error in the title.

Edit:
As requested in the comments, **wdio version is 5.12.4**.
I'm using cucumber.js so I put `console.log(browser.config)` in my steps but even the IDE (Webstorm) doesn't recognize it [image]
and if I continue to run the test I get the error in the log

```
ERROR @wdio/runner: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
tests/features/step_definitions/steps.ts(84,25): error TS2339: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'BrowserObject'.
```

Comment: The answers you're going to get are as vague as the question you asked. Wait, what question? Paste at least a snippet of your test that is causing the problem. Also more context is in order. I tried `browser.options` & `browser.config` in both v4 & v5 @latest and they work just fine. What WebdriverIO version are you running on?

Comment: Thanks for the feddback @iamdanchiv, I edited my question, hope it's more clear and has better context now, any help is appreciated, thanks. and sorry for the late reply, I didn't see the notification earlier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue in webdriver.io.
It was fixed in commit https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/commit/29690864b30efd163c1c82bc28ac124d7948e519

Fix will be present in v5.15.6